# Missing 'available_countries' information on some track API requests

Tags: deezer

Some of the API requests to get track details are missing the array of *available_countries* in which the track can be played.
For instance this Pink Floyd track:
http://api.deezer.com/track/89569653

But when testing in the API console the available_countries are present for this track ID.

It only seems to happen for some tracks though, for instance the Daft Punk API example does have the *available_countries* data:
http://api.deezer.com/track/3135556

Is it an issue with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node "available_countries" is there but empty, so it just means that the track is not available in any country, it is not an issue. If you check directly in our website www.deezer.com/track/89569653, you will see that the track is not available.

Comment: Ok thanks - although that track does actually play for me!